# How to control speed of animation on Unity by a .txt file?

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, unityscript

I am trying to controlling the flow of an 3D animation on unity through the sound. 
Therefore, through a synthesizer sounds, get the BPM of a song, which are stored in a file. Txt, with the given time and the number of BPM in second. Then in Unity, I have a pre-defined animation, and already carry the file with the information of BPM, but now I do not know how I can make the animation speed is controlled by the information in that file. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can always change AnimationState.speed to serve that purpose.
http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationState-speed.html

Comment: yes I know ... but it changes the speed of the animation as a whole. And that's not what I want. What I want is that the speed of the animation adapts to the information I get from this. Txt file. 
For example, when 5.6 seconds is 180 BPM, and 6.2 seconds is 215 BPM. The logic would be the animation speed go-adapting to the music.

Comment: You could constantly convert [6.2 seconds is 215 BPM] to timescale and set that value to AnimationState.speed in your Update()